# Node.js setTimout not waiting

Tags: javascript, node.js, timeout

I have been using setTimeout for a long time nevertheless I can not explain my node js timeout ignoring the wait time.

Here the blamed code (in Node 8.11.3):

```
//Here is the issue
socket.on('GameInput', function (input, state) {
    setTimeout(socket.player.input, 10000, input, state);
});

//The player constructor is pretty standard
const _PLAYER = function(socket, name) {
    //properties
    this.input = function(input, state) {
        //dosomestuff
        io.emit('GameInput', this.name, input, state);
    }
}
```

I am just making a fake lag on the player inputs (to test play-ability) and whatever milliseconds I write there is no effect.

Edit :
The real problem is that i do not restart my node server correctly ...
The good code is indeed
setTimeout(()=>{socket.player.input(input, state);}, 10000);
I tried it but without restart the effect is not such visible -__-

Comment: why are you passing the arguments like that and not like this: `setTimeout(socket.player.input(input, state), 10000);`?

Comment: Thanks for the try but we must not use called function in timeouts. I tried to dodge this problem not calling it and passing the arguments according to the documentation but it fail the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the function in the timeout in a function call, otherwise you are calling the function, not passing it through to be completed when the timeout ends.

Something like this:

`socket.on('GameInput', function (input, state) {
    setTimeout(function() { socket.player.input(input, state) }, 10000);
});`

Comment: Indeed this works better, but I was sure the 2 writing was equivalent. I know we must not return called function, I thought without the '()' the setTimeout will store it for later.